# Why is it that I cannot seem to install Minecraft Forge (Version 11.14.1.1334 Minecraft 1.8)?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, windows-8.1

Each time I go to install it, I get the error message **"You need to run the version 1.8 manually at least once"** of which I have already done. My system runs **Windows 8.1** and I have the most up to date version of Minecraft. I was hoping to install the Too Much TNT mod, but it doesn't look very likely to happen at the moment.

I do run the install using Java, and I am sure that my Java is up to date.

Answer (score 1):

Your profile is probably set to latest so you are probably using Minecraft version 1.8.2. You need to [change your profile](http://www.howtogeek.com/203196/how-to-change-your-minecraft-game-version-and-set-up-profiles/) to use version 1.8 explicitly and launch it to be able to install forge.

Comment: Thanks for your response. How do I do that?

Comment: http://www.howtogeek.com/203196/how-to-change-your-minecraft-game-version-and-set-up-profiles/ (Information is true, tested confirmed.)

Comment: Then, if a more uptodate version of Minecraft Forge comes out for 1.8.2, what do I do then?

Comment: If you get 1.8 working then you'll know what to do for other versions :)

Comment: Now I've done what I supposedly need to do for TooMuchTNT mod and that won't show up. What have I done wrong?

Comment: That mod only works for Minecraft 1.7.10 it seems, not sure if there is one for 1.8